# Empty result in Google speech client api

Tags: c#, angular, google-speech-api

I am trying to implement speech recognition using Google speech api.

I record a raw audio on my web page and then send the raw file to server where it is trying to recognize by using Google's speech api.

Here is my angular code

```
start() {
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    this.mediaRecorder.start();

    const audioChunks = [];

    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/wav"});
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

      this.fileService.saveFile(audioBlob).subscribe(res => { console.log(res); });

      const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
      audio.play();
    });
  });
}
```

Here is my C# controller code'

```
    private string GetSpeechToText()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.Create();

            RecognitionConfig config = new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en-US",
            };

            RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.Recognize(config,
                RecognitionAudio.FromFile(fileName));

            foreach (var responseResult in response.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in responseResult.Alternatives)
                {
                    result += alternative.Transcript;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The audio plays fine both on client side and the server side file after getting written to file.

I have included the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS path correctly.

But I am getting empty response. Please tell me if I am missing something

Comment: I guess my file doesn't have a proper wav header and hence it is not recognized as on. Does anyone know how to convert audio buffer to Wav

Comment: How long is your audio file? Recognize() supports file less than 1 minute.

Comment: @wannadream Its not longer than 10 seconds or so..